# how to point a box2d body in the direction of motion?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Hi guys as the title suggest i want to move a box2d body the direction of motion .. can anyone give some clue how can i achieve this ? Thanks

right now i am using

```
b->SetLinearImpusle(force,direciton);
```

the body just rotates according to the collision

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to apply an impulse in specified direction:

```
b2Vec2 direction(1, 0);
direction.Normalize();
float force = 10.0f;
b->ApplyLinearImpulse(force*direction, b->GetPosition());
```

the second parameter of ApplyLinearImpulse is the point where to apply the impulse

Comment: this is fine but after the body collides to the boundary the body is supposed to rotate the the angle in which the body is moving after collision ... any idea?

Comment: use b2ContactListener to react on collisions

Comment: can you explain the b2Vec2 direction(1, 0); in which direction will the body move?

Comment: @JayGajjar: in the positive direction of `x` axis